# ELB with OutOfService Instances in Eucalyptus

Tags: cloud, load-balancing, eucalyptus

I'm trying to configure ELB in Eucalyptus private cloud, but the instances remain OutOfService. What procedure do I need to let them InService?

[root@frontend Downloads]# eulb-describe-instance-health loadbalancer
INSTANCE    i-A05B431F  OutOfService
INSTANCE    i-B0223F33  OutOfService

**follows the log:**

root@ip-172-31-254-93 ~]# tail -16 /var/log/load-balancer-servo/servo.log
failed to query the elb service: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11
failed to find the loadbalancers
403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11
failed to report the cloudwatch metrics: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:11
403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21
failed to query the elb service: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21
failed to find the loadbalancers
403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21
failed to report the cloudwatch metrics: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
`403 Forbidden`Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21Message has expired (times in UTC): Timestamp=null Expires=null Deadline=2014-10-23T18:00:21
[root@ip-172-31-254-93 ~]#

Answer (score 0):

This question was [asked and answered](https://groups.google.com/a/eucalyptus.com/d/msg/euca-users/7HiTon7R2IM/QnEfVnRr-6AJ) on the euca-users mailing list. This issue is covered in the documentation of [troubleshooting for ELB](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.0.2/index.html#troubleshooting-guide/ts_elb.html).